# Ionic v1 - How to display dynamic quiz questions on ion-slide-box and save user answer

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic-v1

I'm working on ionic v1 MCQ quiz app and looking for a solution to how display the questions on quiz test page. Was already tried to search through Google but nothing found a complete reference for it then decided to post here. After spending few hours on Google search I comes to know that it might possible with [ion-slide-box](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v1/api/directive/ionSlides/) but not 100% sure.

Here is my requirements -

I was used PHP/MySQL for Rest API. All questions are MCQ only with 4 options and if user tap/click on any of option for a current question answer will save user answer through rest API and move to next questions (shuffle). When user tap/click on last question option app with navigate to result page $state.go(app.finish).

Sample Question JSON data what I get through PHP Rest API -

```
[
    {
      "id":"1",
      "title":"Grand Central Terminal, Park Avenue, New York is the world's",
      "options":
            [
              {"value": "largest railway station","iscorrectans":true},
              {"value": "highest railway station","iscorrectans":false},
              {"value": "longest railway station","iscorrectans":false},
              {"value": "None of the above","iscorrectans":false}
            ]
    },
    {
      "id":"2",
      "title":"Eighteen thousandths, written as a decimal, is",
      "options":
            [
              {"value": "0.0018","iscorrectans":false},
              {"value": "0.018","iscorrectans":false},
              {"value": "0.18","iscorrectans":true},
              {"value": "18","iscorrectans":false}
            ]
    },
    {
      "id":"3",
      "title":"Eighteen thousandths, written as a decimal, is",
      "options":
            [
              {"value": "0.0018","iscorrectans":false},
              {"value": "0.018","iscorrectans":false},
              {"value": "0.18","iscorrectans":true},
              {"value": "18","iscorrectans":false}
            ]
    },
    {
      "id":"4",
      "title":"Eighteen thousandths, written as a decimal, is",
      "options":
            [
              {"value": "0.0018","iscorrectans":false},
              {"value": "0.018","iscorrectans":false},
              {"value": "0.18","iscorrectans":true},
              {"value": "18","iscorrectans":false}
            ]
    },
    {
      "id":"5",
      "title":"Eighteen thousandths, written as a decimal, is",
      "options":
            [
              {"value": "0.0018","iscorrectans":false},
              {"value": "0.018","iscorrectans":false},
              {"value": "0.18","iscorrectans":true},
              {"value": "18","iscorrectans":false}
            ]
    }
  ]
```

Comment: May this tutorial will help you https://www.joshmorony.com/create-a-data-driven-quiz-app-in-ionic-2-part-1/ . It is not in ionic1 but you can get idea from that.

Comment: Thanks! But I was looking for ionic v1 example

Answer (score 0):

I did a little example for you in angularjs with css transform property, you can do better with angular-animate but this is a base for your project, you can select answer, increment score, change question and have a result page.

You do not need ion-slide-box to do what you want.

[example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angularjs-quiz)